# deleting a student record from a single linked list

Tags: c

This is the code i have written to delete a particular student record in a linked list:

```
int delete ( struct student **q, struct student s,char *n ) {
    if(*q==NULL)
    {
        printf("The linked list is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    struct student *prev=*q;
    while(prev->link!=NULL && prev->link!=n)
    {
        prev=prev->link;
    }
    if(prev->link==NULL)
    {
        printf("Student %s not found\n",n);
        return 0;
    }
    prev->link=prev->link->link;
    free(n);
    return 1;
}
```

but i am getting a warning message telling `comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]` for the while statement `while(prev->link!=NULL && prev->link!=n)`

This is the structure:

```
struct student
{
  int id;
  char name[10];
  char gender[10];
  struct student * link;
}*head;
```

and `n` stores the name of the student that has to be deleted.

Comment: show us `struct student`

Comment: also, `prev->link!=n` what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: n is a char * but prev->link is a student * so you want to compare student names such as strcmp( prev->link->name, n ) == 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things not really working in your code.

I think you want to remove the whole struct matching the char* n from the linked list.

You cannot compare char*n and a struct, so this loop is incorrect:

```
while(prev->link!=NULL && prev->link!=n)
{
    prev=prev->link;
}
```

You need to check if the first one doesn't match with your string, otherwise it would remain. If the first one matches, you need to reallocate the beginning of the struct, so you would use a **q in the declaration of the function (be sure to properly impact it). The first check would look like:

```
struct student *prev = *q;
if (strcmp(prev->name, n) == 0)
{
    *q = (*q)->link;
    prev->link = NULL; //not compulsory, but a good habit to take
    free(prev);
}
```

I would write the loop this way :

```
while(prev->link != NULL && strcmp(prev->link->name, n) != 0))
    {
        prev = prev->link;
    }
```

In C, you need to use strcmp() to compare two strings. 
The no-match "if" would then remain identical.

Then, you have some issues with memory allocation. You cannot free fixed pointers (name[10] for instance), but only malloced memory.
So the end, after the no-match if, I advise a "else" that would look like:

```
else
{
     struct student matched_student = prev->link;
     prev->link = prev->link->link; 
     matched_student->link = NULL;
     free(matched_student);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the type of `prev->link` is `struct student *`, but the type of `n` is `char *`, those type is different, so you can use

```
static_cast<char *>(prev->link) != n
```

or

```
(char *)(prev->link) != n
```

to fix the warning.

Comment: thank u so much.. the error is cleared. but instead of deleting the student record i am getting the output as linked list empty :(